# Usage of "Buttocks"

Tags: word-usage

Is it decent to the word "buttocks" in writings? Is there a better decent word to mean the same? Is Butt is considered more decent and acceptable than "buttocks"?

I want a word to mean the same thing, but it should decent enough and commonly used.

Comment: It depends on the context. Is this a medical context? (The patient had a puncture wound in his buttocks). Or more of a proverbial usage of the word? (For example, _She needs a good kick in the buttocks;_ or, _This new insurance form is a pain in the buttocks to fill out_; or, _That movie was so funny, I was laughing by buttocks off_.) Or something you might say to a young child? (_Make sure you wipe your buttocks when you are finished_). The words _tail, butt, hiney, bum, posterior_, and _derrière_, can all function as euphemisms, but I wouldn't say those are all interchangeable.

Comment: @J.R. Yes, it's related to medical context. "He touches his buttocks with his hand and looks at his hand - there's a small dot of blood." I didn't mean bleeding ass here. Doctor injected medicine in his buttocks. :)

Comment: From an exercise perspective, you might use [_glutes_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/glute), as in: _These exercises really work the upper legs and the glutes_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Buttocks* is the preferred term in formal writing: politer and more formal than *butt* (AmE) and *bum* (BrE), which are colloquial, and *arse* (BrE) or *ass* (AmE), which are vulgar.

Other terms, such as *posterior* or *fundament* (formal), *bottom* (ambiguous in some contexts), *backside* (informal) and a host of more or less infantine colloquialisms (*hiney*, *keister*, *booty*, etc.<sup>†</sup>) are too nakedly euphemistic to be acceptable in straightforward formal writing.

---

<sup>†</sup>Readers are invited to expand this list.

Comment: Nice. 'Bottom' seems least vulgar for me. Do you think if I use bottom instead of buttocks in the following sentence, it will be ambiguous?  "He touches his buttocks with his hand and looks at his hand - there's a small dot of blood." For me it seems okay and no ambiguous here. I just imagined, what others would interpret this sentence without context. I couldn't stop laughing. :D Don't laugh. I didn't mean bleeding ass here. Doctor injected medicine in his buttocks. :)

Comment: @T2E *Bottom* is marginal. It strikes my ear as childish, and in some contexts it is a euphemistic term for a woman's genitals. And I always recall Boswell's story about Dr. Johnson: "Talking of a very respectable authour, he told us a curious circumstance in his life, which was, that he had married a printer's devil. REYNOLDS. 'A printer's devil, Sir! Why, I thought a printer's devil was a creature with a black face and in rags.' JOHNSON. 'Yes, Sir. But I suppose, he had her face washed, and put clean clothes on her. (Then looking very serious, and very earnest.) ... (*continue*)

Comment: And she did not disgrace him; the woman had a bottom of good sense.' The word bottom thus introduced, was so ludicrous when contrasted with his gravity, that most of us could not forbear tittering and laughing; though I recollect that the Bishop of Killaloe kept his countenance with perfect steadiness, while Miss Hannah More slyly hid her face behind a lady's back who sat on the same settee with her. ... (*continue*)

Comment: His pride could not bear that any expression of his should excite ridicule, when he did not intend it; he therefore resolved to assume and exercise despotick power, glanced sternly around, and called out in a strong tone, 'Where's the merriment?' Then collecting himself, and looking aweful, to make us feel how he could impose restraint, and as it were searching his mind for a still more ludicrous word, he slowly pronounced, 'I say the WOMAN was FUNDAMENTALLY sensible;' as if he had said, hear this now, and laugh if you dare. We all sat composed as at a funeral."

Comment: @T2E In that case, I might argue for “(left | right) buttock” (specified, formal, singular).

Comment: StoneyB, the word *butt* in this context, is also AmE. The words *hiney*, *keister* and *booty* are unfamiliar here in the UK. I suspect that they also, are American.

Comment: @Tristan Yes; *butt* has been around a long time. I identified only *ass* and *arse* as regional variants; and I invite others to expand the other list because a) there are too many American terms to clutter the argument with, and b)I don't know the BrE equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

The comments above make it clear it's in a medical interaction (doctor and patient), so the key questions is this:

Who's speaking?

- **A doctor or other medical professional will most often say "buttocks."**  I think it's the most common clinical term.
- **A patient or layperson would generally say "butt."**  Most non-prpofessionals only say "buttocks" if they are trying to deliberately choose clinical (medical) terminology.

Age is a factor here - younger Americans use "ass" in pretty mixed company, and older folk might tend to say "rump" or "rear," but the best guess for an average American who is trying to avoid any vulgarity is pretty surely "butt."

See the Google ngram:
[image]

NGrams are based on written frequency, not verbal, but they're often pretty similar, and they make it pretty clear that the most common terms are "butt" and "ass."

Comment: Buttocks is also used in medical situations because it gives you the opportunity to specify "left" or "right", which none of the singular words (rump, rear, butt, etc) will let you do without adding more words ("left side of my rump").

Comment: *Butt* and *ass* are American English in particular. In England and the rest of the UK, they would translate into *bum* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bum_1?q=bum and *arse* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/arse_1?topic=the-buttocks.

Comment: Another thing to note with this ngram is that the top two words are often used with very different senses. (Cigarette butt, make an ass of oneself.) So this doesn't tell us that "butt" and "ass" are the most common terms for "buttocks".

Comment: @larsh, good point!  My assessment came before I saw it, so I still think it's likely right, but that does cloud how much the ngram 
supports it.

Comment: Google's most carefully curated set of data is 1800 - 2000.  You'll often notice large changes at the year 2000 (as in this graph) if you set the end of the range to 2008, but these changes might not actually be significant.